# Particle-like wifi configuration

Tags: wifi

Can anybody tell me how the [Particle (Photon/Core)](https://docs.particle.io/guide/getting-started/start/core/) WiFi *setup* works?

I am looking to mimic this WiFi configuration format for my own device.

The basic steps are as follows:

1. Power device on; put in "listening mode" if not already active;
2. Connect smartphone to the wireless network that you want to connect your device to;
3. Open the Tinker/Spark/whatever-it's-called App on your smartphone; choose "Add New Device";
4. Enter wireless password;
5. Wait for device to be discovered by the App; device is now connected to WiFi.

How is the information (SSID, password) transferred from the smartphone to the device?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you on about [WPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wi-Fi_Protected_Setup)?

Comment: What does this have to do with Arduinos?

Comment: @NickGammon It has as much to do with Arduinos as the Intel Edison, Galileo and the Teensy range. Those are welcome here, should the Particle/Spark system not be too?

Comment: Oh well, what is the question here? `Any idea how does particle (photon/core) wifi works` - that's too broad then.

Comment: I've edited the question so that it asks about the *wireless setup*, which I think is a valid and non-broad question. I'd also like to know the answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Particle Photon is a replacement for the Spark Core module. This module was exploiting the Texas Instrument CC3000 chip. It was this chip that handle the very simple and convenient Wi-Fi configuration of the Spark Core. Texas Instrument named this method : [SimpleLink](http://www.ti.com/ww/en/simplelink_embedded_wi-fi/tools_software.html).

The Particle Photon is now using a different module than the Core : a Broadcom BCM43362 instead of the CC3000. It's seems to work in a similar manner even if I was not able to find any information on it.

I've found on the George Howkins [Depletion Region blog](http://depletionregion.blogspot.fr/)  multiple articles that explain how the CC3000 SimpleLink works.

- [CC3000 Smart Config - transmitting SSID and keyphrase](http://depletionregion.blogspot.fr/2013/10/cc3000-smart-config-transmitting-ssid.html)
- [CC3000 advertises presence on network via DNS-SD](http://depletionregion.blogspot.fr/2013/10/cc3000-advertises-presence-on-network.html)

All the posts : http://depletionregion.blogspot.fr/search?q=smart+config